# How to get a KAZA Univisa?

Tags: visas, zimbabwe, zambia, botswana, kaza-univisa

The KAZA Univisa program [has been resumed](http://www.zambiainvest.com/tourism/kaza-univisa-2016-resume) and now includes Botswana in addition to Zambia and Zimbabwe. Nevertheless there is little information about this multi-country visa. The linked note states that you can "acquire it at an entry Point of Sale (POS) at Lusaka, Livingstone and Ndola airports", but is it possible to get it on a land border? Or may I get it online or at the embassy?

Comment: From [Smartraveller for Zimbabwe](http://smartraveller.gov.au/Countries/africa/east/Pages/zimbabwe.aspx): ***Latest advice, 28 September 2016** The UNIVISA system is currently suspended. If travelling between Zimbabwe and Zambia more than once either way, you should get a double entry visa [...]*

Comment: That's the point, the information about the UNIVISA is not very reliable. In my country's goverment page (Spain) is still available the UNIVISA so it's really impossible to know the real state due their website is offline at least one week.. :?

Comment: I would try contacting your local embassy, those of my country usually respond within a couple of days with excellent advice. That being said, what I find is that the Univisa program has in fact not been resumed and that in any case you are advised not to rely on it but get your visa from an embassy in advance.

Comment: Found same advice for Zambia from [UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/zambia/entry-requirements): "*The Kaza UNIVISA is temporarily suspended until further notice. If you’re planning to travel between Livingstone, Zambia and Victoria Falls, Zimbabwe, you’ll need to apply for a visa for each of the countries.*" Will post all of this as an answer later, but you should start applying for regular visa.

Answer (score 5):

**As of August 2017, the KAZA Univisa is once again operational**

Following a successful pilot, the KAZA Univisa has been [reinstated](http://www.victoriafalls-guide.net/great-news-the-kaza-univisa-is-back.html) to allow holders unlimited access to both Zambia and Zimbabwe for 30 days, as well as limited day trip access to the Kazungula region of Botswana.  (The UK travel guidelines have been updated to further [confirm](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/zimbabwe/entry-requirements) this)

According to the [official website](http://www.kazavisa.info/index.php/about/zambia-zimbabwe-visa-info), permits can be obtained in person at the following locations by people with eligible passports (listed in the link), for a fee of 50 USD:

In Zambia:

- Harry Mwaanga Airport (Livingstone)
- Victoria Falls Land Border  -
- Kazungula Land Border (border with Botswana)
- Kenneth Kaunda Airport (Lusaka)

In Zimbabwe:

- Victoria Falls Airport
- Victoria Falls Land Border
- Kazungula Land Border (border with Botswana)
- Harare Airport

Answer (score 2):

## The Univisa program is inactive, get regular visa for both countries.

[Consular info for Zambia from gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/zambia/entry-requirements)

> The Kaza UNIVISA is temporarily suspended until further notice. If you’re planning to travel between Livingstone, Zambia and Victoria Falls, Zimbabwe, you’ll need to apply for a visa for each of the countries.

[Same for Zimbabwe](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/zimbabwe/entry-requirements)

> The UNIVISA system (which allowed travellers to enter both Zimbabwe and Zambia using a dual visa) is currently suspended. If you’re travelling between Zimbabwe and Zambia (more than one entry either way), you should get a double entry visa for both countries. Both Zimbabwe and Zambia issue double entry visas at ports of entry.

And confirmed by the [Aussie travel advice](http://smartraveller.gov.au/Countries/africa/east/Pages/zimbabwe.aspx)

> **Latest advice, 28 September 2016**
>   The UNIVISA system is currently suspended. If travelling between Zimbabwe and Zambia more than once either way, you should get a double entry visa [...]

There is a [related discussion on a tripadvisor forum](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293759-i9323-k9134475-o10-KAZA_Uni_Visa_Suspended_in_Zambia_and_Zimbabwe-Zimbabwe.html) and reports are that the program is suspended from posts as late as May and June 2016, which however still precede the article you cite. To be honest I doubt your source somewhat, since it is an investment website for Zambia and seems to me they copied some official blabla without checking much, but that's just my two cents.